# Show only top records in pivottable excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter my pivottable for the top 10 rows through vba. The manual way is depicted in the picure, to make clear what I mean.

[image]

I have tried the following so far, but I can not get this to work. (ObjField refers here to the Count of Creation Date.)

```
objField.AutoShow Type:=xlAutomatic, Range:=xlTop, Count:=10, Field:="Count of Creation Date"
```

I am sure the objfield reference itself is correct, since other adjustments to the pivottable through the code are working just fine. It is however possible that I am using the wrong pivotfield here. Any help with this minor problem would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Full code; called from access:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet

Dim xlpiv As PivotTable
Dim objField As PivotField
Dim RowField As PivotField
Dim valueField As PivotField

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(OutPutFileName)
Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

    xlBook.Sheets("Qry_CustomsReport").Select
    Set xlpiv = xlSheet1.PivotTableWizard

    Set objField = xlpiv.PivotFields("NEA Plant Codes")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = xlpiv.PivotFields("Creation Date")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
    Set RowField = objField

    Set objField = xlpiv.PivotFields("Creation Date")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlCount
    Set valueField = objField

    RowField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=valueField, Value1:=10

    xlpivC.ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable Plant"
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a variable of the type `PivotField` to the parameter `Field` - not a string with the name of the field!

Comment: Changing to `Field:=objField` throws back a '1004' error. 'Application or object-defined error'. It does this whether `ObjField` refers to the datafield or the columnfield. Is there another field I need to refer to?

Comment: Did you try to record macro with actions you want to perform?

Comment: I have now, and it has indeed worked out. the problem is however, that I am working via access. Is there a way to refer to this macro via access each time there is a new report created? If you post your answer as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I do not have access experience or knowledge. Maybe try to ask another question, this time with access and excel tags.

Comment: Found the correct syntax and ref for the `autoshow` command thanks to this macro recorder. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, this problem is solved now, Thanks to lowak and peter for pointing me in the right direction. The macro recorder on my part, however, came up with a different line of code;

```
xlSheet4pivCT.PivotFields("NEA Plant Codes").AutoShow _
    xlAutomatic, xlTop, 10, "Count of Creation Date"
```

It seems the code I tried to use at the start turned out to be the correct one, but with the wrong references. Thank you guys for showing this macro recorder, which will definitely come in handy later on.

Comment: Great that you figured it! The macro recorder is really useful when trying to figure out syntax/Excel object model questions. Just be aware of it's pitfall, see esp. #1 of this link: http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-excels-macro-recorder-to-learn-vba/

Comment: Thanks for the interesting read! Might've been a good thing I didn't discover this sooner. Now it can be a good help into getting the correct references like this time!

Answer (score 2):

According to the macro recorder, try this syntax:

```
Set pivTable = PivotTables("YourPivotTable")

'The field you want the filter:
Set rowField = pivTable.PivotFields("TheRowField") 

'The aggregation you to use to determine the top 10:
Set valueField = pivTable.PivotFields("Count of Creation Date") 

rowField.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=valueField, Value1:=10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work, even with changing `.add2` to `.add` and/or trying different fields. I shall put my full code in the original post, since I may be making a mistake somewhere along the way.